# vscode: how to setup a workspace by providing a master file list?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Some IDEs support a feature usually called "master filelist", that the user provides a simple text file containing all files for a project, thus the IDE only parses the listed files.

Is it possible with vscode workspace? Note that I am aware of the "Exclude" feature of vscode, but it is not convenient for my use case.

Thanks.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a [Stack Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/?more_on=xron.net). See How to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It also very helpful to show in your Question an expected result, and quote any (exact) errors you are getting. You are expected to show any research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: there is an extension that allows you to setup a starting collection of files in a workspace

Comment: @rioV8 Thanks for your reply. Do you remember the name of the extension?

Answer (score 0):

After trying many methods (all in vain), I came up with the following workaround: make symlinks to all files in the master filelist.

Suppose that the files in the filelist (`${ABS_INCLUDE}`) are with absolute pathes, and suppose they share a root directory (which can be always true), then first create a dedicated root directory (`SYM_ROOT_DIR`) for vscode workspace, and then create symlinks for each files under the new root directory, e.g.,

```
 mkdir -p ${SYM_ROOT_DIR}
 while IFS= read -r line
 do
     OLD_DIR=$(dirname "$line")
     BASENAME=$(basename "$line")
     SYM_DIR=$(echo "${OLD_DIR}" | sed "s@${ABS_ROOT_DIR}@${SYM_ROOT_DIR}@")
     mkdir -p ${SYM_DIR}
     ln -s ${line} ${SYM_DIR}/${BASENAME}
 done < ${ABS_INCLUDE}
```